# Convert Subquery To Join For Use As View

Tags: mysql, join, view, subquery

Can I shorten the time of execution when I create a view? I would like to optimize the execution time but apparently I cant alter the table to add indexes to it.

Also, can I rewrite this query using JOIN?

I want to optimize the time of the execution of the query.

```
 select
   Empcode
 , Name
 , Department
 , in_datetime
 , out_datetime
 , date_format(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,in_datetime,out_datetime)),'%H:%i:%S') as duration
 from (
  select
        (select Empcode from spmm_employee_info c where logs_spmm.Pin=c.Empcode or logs_spmm.pin=c.Pin) as Empcode, (select Name from spmm_employee_info e where logs_spmm.pin=e.Empcode or logs_spmm.pin=e.Pin) as Name
   ,(select Department from spmm_employee_info e where logs_spmm.pin=e.Empcode) as Department
      , date_time as in_datetime
      , (select s.Date_time from logs_spmm as s 
     where s.Date_time>logs_spmm.Date_time and s.Mode='OUT' and s.Pin=logs_spmm.Pin limit 1) as out_datetime
  from logs_spmm
  where mode = 'IN' 
) as relog
```

Comment: Creating a view and optimizing execution time are two different things. Which do you want, or which do you want most?

Comment: When you say, "can't add indexes," do you mean you *aren't allowed to do so,* or is there some other factor at work here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at my solution now and thinking, "I must have missed something!" Three of the subqueries have collapsed into a single `INNER JOIN`, and the last subquery might or might not collapse if I knew more about the data; if it did then the outer `SELECT` could probably go away as well.

The three subqueries in question:

```
...
(select Empcode from spmm_employee_info c
    where logs_spmm.Pin=c.Empcode or logs_spmm.pin=c.Pin)
  as Empcode,
(select Name from spmm_employee_info e
    where logs_spmm.pin=e.Empcode or logs_spmm.pin=e.Pin)
  as Name,
(select Department from spmm_employee_info e
    where logs_spmm.pin=e.Empcode)
  as Department
...
```

are selecting three different columns from the same table, and using the same `WHERE` condition to do it so, (assuming an employee can be uniquely identified by either `pin` or `empcode`,) all three subqueries should select the **same single** row in `spmm_employee_info`. This means that they can be collapsed into a **single subquery** which returns all three columns. This gives a subquery returning a single row for each row in the parent query; this can be turned into a simple inner join by taking the subquery's `WHERE` clause and `AND`ing it with that of the parent query.